Error - ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC while trying to deploy to app service
I am getting below error while deploying app service via team city build server.
msdeploy error ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC: Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ( using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond.)

I have already tried everything mentioned here

I am able to deploy from Visual Studio publish mechanism.
Able to ping .scm url from build server.
Restarted the app service and tried deploying but same error.
Disabled TLS 1.0 and enabled TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 on build server but getting same error.
Able to open Kudu .scm url.
App service has no access restrictions.
Able to deploy to different Cloud service from same build server.

Can anybody help me?

Found the issue! The build server was using outdated username and password from the publish profile inside project properties. Once we updated that it started working fine. The error from Microsoft is so misleading which made us believe that server is unavailable somehow.
